# When using Firefox v.12 on Windows 7, pressing <tab> acts equivalent to <Alt>+<tab>

Tags: keyboard

Why is my instance of Windows 7 showing the equivalent of alt+tab when I press the tab button in Firefox v.12 and how do I stop it?

Comment: Does it only do this while in Firefox?  Which version of FF?  Does it do it while in Safe Mode?  How about if you run FF with no add-ons?  Did it always do this, or is this new?

Comment: To clarify @techie007's question, this is not normal behavior, so further details about what you're seeing and your exact configuration are helpful.

Comment: Press each of the modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift) on both sides of the keyboard to make sure the system doesn't think they are stuck down or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use the same keyboard on some other machines. If the condition is reproducible, then there is definitely issue with your keyboard. Then I guess replacing it would solve your problem.